# Backbone.js - How to use 'ul' 'li' tags as tab widget using MVC?

Tags: backbone.js

The question may confuse you, I want to achieve the 'tab' widget from 'ul' and 'li' tags using 'Backbone.js' and it's MVC concept. How to do?

For example

```
<ul>
  <li> One </li>
  <li> Two </li>
  <li> Three </li>
</ul>
```

When the link 'one' is clicked then I want to show some content (div) and want to hide others how to do using MVC concept ?

This could be done without Backbone and MVC, but I want to do this with Backbone, please help me.

Comment: And the question is: those tab names are fixed or you want them generated from some collection?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Backbone.View that will handle all of your "tabs". This Backbone.View should cover the  or whatever is above your content.

Based on your ul, you can add CSS selectors or other attributes:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab-one">One</li>
        <li class="tab-two">Two</li>
        <li class="tab-three">Threeli>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">...</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Create a Backbone.View to handle the page events:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#mainDiv'),
    events: {
    'click .tab-one': 'showTabOne',
    'click .tab-two': 'showTabTwo',
    'click .tab-three': 'showTabThree'
    },
    showTabOne: function() {
        $(this.el).find('.tab').hide();
        $(this.el).find('#tab1').show();
    },
    showTabTwo: function() {
        $(this.el).find('.tab').hide();
        $(this.el).find('#tab2').show();
    },
    showTabThree: function() {
        $(this.el).find('.tab').hide();
        $(this.el).find('#tab3').show();
    }
    ...
}
```

This is just to show and hide tabs using Backbone. You can do a lot more with Backbone :)

Edit: If you're tab list is dynamic, you can put the initialization of events using jquery way inside the Backbone.View's initialize() function. This will get invoked once you instantiate a Backbone.View (var view = new MyView;)

Comment: Really nice, I will try then let you know the status. How to initialize other view (and render the view) from the event handlers 'showTabOne()'

Comment: Normally, there would be a "main" Backbone.View for a page. This will control other sub-Backbone.Views. So you can just instantiate your main Backbone.View in your JS (e.g. var mainView = new MyView) This will initialize the view and set up all event handlers. If you have other views, you can do the same thing. It depends on how you organize your page.